# Magento + Redis, full session catalogs?

Tags: magento, session, redis

Correct configured Magento and Redis will keep /var/session and var/cache catalog empty all the time?

I don’t know why but I have a lot files inside – few hundreds MB, also via SSH file /var/redis/6379/dump.rdb has few MB.

Please advise is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right, Magento is heavily reliant on cache to increase performance. If you go to the admin panel:

`System > Cache Management`

You will see that there are 9 cache types such as layout, blocks, eav. So basically magento will cache all of the views and even some of the database data such as products. Magento's main selling point is that it can handle lots of data associated to products and such, so for any sizeable store this is correct.